Mechanism to rotate a mirror
I would like to design a mirror mount that allows me to switch its orientation between vertical and horizontal without changing the direction it is facing during the motion.
It is for a standard-use mirror with dimensions ranging from 150-170cm x 45-60cm, made of whatever material such mirrors are typically made of. I believe they are made of glass with an aluminum or silver coating applied to the back of the glass.
I’ve been exploring some mechanisms, such as the double-slider crank mechanism, but I’m unsure if they are suitable for this application. Since I’m new to design and there’s so much information out there, I think it’s better to ask if someone has any ideas on how this could be achieved.
A hand-drawn sketch or guidance on where to place pivots or what type of mechanism to use would be incredibly helpful.
Edit:
The mirror will be supported by a stand that rests on the floor. It will not be mounted on the wall.
I would like to know what kind of stand allows transitioning from a vertical position to a horizontal position without having to lift the mirror entirely (as is possible with many smartphone stands, but in this case, it’s feasible because smartphones are small).
Below, I’ve included some pictures using LEGO to show an example of how it would look. Assuming the table represents the floor, the stand I’ve added is just an example, but it clearly doesn’t work.




look at car windshield wipers

@jsotola the main thing here is that I want the center of the mirror not to change. That means, if you draw an imaginary line at the center of the vertical-mirror and then you rotate it to horizontal position, that center line should be at the center of the horizontal-mirror

Is this for a full-length mirror, found in a bedroom, or a 1ft tabletop mirror? Please add approx size of the mirror. Is this for a glass mirror, or is material unimportant (eg. polished stainless steel would suffice)?  Perhaps one useful aspect of Design - try to spec out the constraints in terms of size, weight, function etc. Don't over-specify - only spec what is needed so other parameters can be adjusted to allow creativity. And specify a range and/or tolerance of parameters where possible.

@Demis It is for a standard-use mirror with dimensions ranging from 150-170cm x 45-60cm, made of whatever material such mirrors are typically made of. I believe they are made of glass with an aluminum or silver coating applied to the back of the glass.

Thanks that's helpful to picture it.

It's not clear where the mirror is to be mounted.
Your sketch looks like a desk or table stand, in which case you can copy the design of a free-standing picture frame. These have a pull-out leg which will stand the picture in portrait or landscape.
There are mobile phone accessories which do the same job.
If you are wall mounting then a VESA monitor bracket (with pivot) might do the job.

I've edited the original post for clearance

Are you saying you want to rotate the mirror from portrait to landscape while keeping the plane of the mirror vertical? This would be very easy - like the computer monitor stand I'm using now with a portrait monitor - provided that the mirror doesn't have to touch the floor in either end position (so that there's floor clearance for the corners during rotation). Do another edit to your question to clarify further.

that's exactly what I was trying to say, rotate from portrait to landscape while keeping the plane of the mirror vertical. But the stand must be on floor, not wall mounted (I think computer monitor stands are like that or table-attached)

I think the trick here is to have the stand hinge at an angle. However, this would lead to fixed angles of inclination in both "standing" positions. So you loose some flexibility in comparison with classic hinged stand, which can work decently at a range of angles. Maybe you could get both advantages using a rod instead of a plate with an angled hinge.

Mechanism
Either a “Full motion” rotating “360” HD TV mounts might be close to what you want. Some of these have articulating arms:
Google search.
I suspect you’ll want to design and make a larger version of a computer monitor stand, for example this one:

If you also include the ability for the mount to slide up and down the stand (as I have seen in some computer monitor mounts), then one could

rotate the mirror and
push it down to the floor

in 2 separate motions.
Modifications for your application
You’ll need to

enlarge it,
ensure it can handle the weight of a glass mirror (quite heavy!),
Add a sliding vertical movement mechanism such as springs/pneumatic to make lifting easier and
Ensure all the edges especially corners are rubberized/buffered to prevent breakage during rotation, should a corner collide with the floor.

If you are designing from scratch, then you could possibly add gears to the bac that couple the vertical motion to the rotation motion, enabling both at the same time.
Mirror Material
To reduce some of these constraints, I think you could replace the glass mirror with a lighter and more durable Polished Stainless Steel sheet. We have such a stainless steel mirror at my work, it works well. This may make the system less prone to breakage and easier to lift/adjust.
However one risk/drawback is that any warping would negatively affect the mirror - so you’d need to ensure the mounts are very rigid.

And most of those have a spring or gas-strut assisted lift so there is very little weight.

@Demis, Transistor I believe that a monitor stand like the one you propose could be too unstable, considering that the mirror is larger and heavier. Furthermore, this also makes it difficult to include an adjustment mechanism to keep it at a fixed height.

I’m suggesting you take this mechanism and design your own to make it larger and able to handle the much higher weight of a glass mirror. (BTW it’s possible that polished stainless steel might be lighter & more durable - but also easier to warp.) For the up-down mechanism, I have computer monitor stands with spring/pneumatic type of resistive-movement placement - meaning you can just push it up or down and it stays. I assume that requires adjustment of the resistance via the pneumatic - not sure really.

I clarified in the answer

See above link to "full motion 360 HD TV mount" - maybe that will do what you want with less modification.  Might be similar weight.
